# How to do looping that contain if statement in dart language

Tags: loops, for-loop, dart

I am trying to do looping in dart with 100 data, but I am confused how to do it inside if statement... what I mean is..
usually I am able doing this with some data

```
if(x[0]<5 || x[1]<5 || x[2]<5){
      //do something
  }
```

but... inside `if` statement, I want to define 100 data.. I want to do like this

```
if(x[0]<5 || x[1]<5 || x[2]<5 ||....|| x[99]<5){
      //do something
  }
```

is that possible to do that using `for` looping since I have `||` (or) condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `any`

```
void main() {
  var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  if (x.any((v) => v < 5)) {        //true
    print("atleast one is less than 5");
  }

  var y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  if (y.any((v) => v > 50)) {        //false
    print("atleast one is more than 50");
  }
}
```

tested on dartpad

Comment: that's perfect...like what I want.. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score -1):

As [Doc answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837808/), using `any` is appropriate in your case.

In general (and this applies for any programming languages, not just Dart), if you want a loop, *create a loop*.

```dart
for (var element in x) {
  if (element < 5) {
    // do something

    // Stop looping; equivalent to ||'s short-circuiting behavior.
    break;
  }
}
```